# I can't use MMWormhole within my Watch App Extension

Tags: ios, cocoapods, watchkit

Recently I am trying to do an app using MMWormhole pod. I have been trying to install it via CocoaPods, without success.

After `pod install` if I try to use it in my iOS app, I can. But, when I try to `#import` it within my Watch App Extension, It says:

[image]

My podfile looks like following:

```
target :'Main Target', :exclusive => true do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  pod 'MMWormhole'
end

target :'Watch App Extension', :exclusive => true do
  platform :ios, '8.0'
  pod 'MMWormhole'
end
```

Anyone can help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: any solution for this error?